# Repeated event firing with ng-click in nested div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing problem because I have a checkbox inside a div and I want to call a function in both the cases: **if we change the checkbox value** or **click the div**.

Now the problem is that, When I click the checkbox, The event is fired twice and I am not getting expected result.

```
<div ng-click="checkEntry(config.id)"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="modelCheckbox" ng-change="checkEntry(config.id)" ng-checked="someArray.indexOf(config.id) !== -1"></div>

$scope.checkEntry = function(id){
    var idx = $scope.someArray.indexOf(id);
    if(idx === -1){
        $scope.someArray.push(id);
    }else{
        $scope.someArray.splice(idx, 1);
    }
}
```

Now If i click div, it works fine and the checkbox gets selected. But if i click the checkBox, the function is called twice, and it doesn't work as expected.

Please help me with a solution

Comment: try adding  `$event.stopPropagation();`  with `ng-click` of div

Comment: when your check box is clicked. its clicked event is fired. and its got propagated to parent element. element which is in parent hierarchy and have click event attached , they will also capture those event. This is called event bubbling. hence you need to call $event.stopPropagation() on your checkbox ng-click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need two event handler for two identical events.When you click on the input, the div will be clicked as well. so you just need to remove ng-change from your code.

```
<div ng-click="checkEntry(config.id)">test
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="modelCheckbox" ng-checked="checked">
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.checked = true;
$scope.checkEntry = function(id){
    $scope.checked = !$scope.checked;
}
```

Look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NiCl0aZtxLBBR9PzSiIy?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox is situated *inside* of that div, so when you click checkbox you are actually clicking also on div.
Actually, in your case you can remove *ng-change* attribute from checkbox and it will still work, because function will be called via click on div anyway. But that is not correct way to work with checkboxes!

First question here is if you really need that div?
I would rather use label instead:

```
<label for="my-checkbox"><input id="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-model="modelCheckbox" ng-change="checkEntry(config.id)" ng-checked="someArray.indexOf(config.id) !== -1"></label>
```

In such case it will work fine, you just need to write proper CSS to style that label correctly. This is the best and the most correct solution.

Comment: Can't realize why this answer is downvoted. No explanations :/
This and Yarmins answers are correct, but the most inconvinient one is marked as a solution.

Comment: your solution works, but May be I did wrong somewhere while implementing which is why not getting the expected result. hence ^1

Comment: So it works for you now, or something still is wrong? If yes, what exactly?

Comment: I used the answer given my Yamin. That works fine for me.